# Handling PHP variable and manipulating PHP variable

Tags: php, html, string, variables, str-replace

I have a variable like this.

```
$my_value = "AU0001AU0012AU0113";
```

The above value needs to be changed like this (expected output).

```
$my_value = "'AU0001','AU0012','AU0113'";
```

How can I do that.

The reason why I want to change is a big store. This is something like string handling/manipulation.

I guess this can be easily addressed by SO-Experts.

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: just one question: how do you fill the `$my_value` var? because in your example they are 3 different values concatenated into a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$string = 'AU0001AU0012AU0113';
preg_match_all('/(AU(\d+))/', $string, $matches);
echo "'" . implode("','", $matches[0]) . "'";
```

Works for different formats as long as they start with AU followed by digits!

Comment: excellent. works perfect. thanks a ton. please upvote my question. someone marked it in negative.

Answer (score 2):

```
$my_value = "AU0001AU0012AU0113";
$arr2 = str_split($my_value, 6);
```

splits the string into an array where each indexx is 6 chars.

Comment: Yep thats good as long as its always that many characters after which they want to split.

Comment: You dont have to trust your memory. Just run the code and find out :)

Answer (score 0):

This will be the full code for you. Take a look at it and comment in case of any questions.

```
<?php

$my_value = "AU0001AU0012AU0113";
$arr = str_split($my_value, 6);
$new_value = "";
$cn = count($arr);
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $i++;
    if ($i == $cn) {
        $new_value .= "'".$val."'";
    }
    else {
        $new_value .= "'".$val."', ";
    }
}
echo $new_value;

?>
```